# Charts with transparent image in jasper reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

Using JFreeChart, Jasper Reports and Jaspersoft Studio, I try to generate the following chart:

[image: expected chart]

But when I generate a PDF in Jaspersoft Studio, I get the following:

[image: resulting chart]

I'm using an image mask with transparency, which corresponds to this:

[image: transparency]

Is there a config in jasper studio/reports that helps to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests, I've found the problem. In Jaspersoft studio, choose the chart of your interest, and In chart options, go to Renderer Type and choose image.